# Why Tulsi not offered to lord Ganesha

Tags: belief, ganesha, puja, tulasi

Why Tulsi is not offered while performing puja to lord Ganesha?

Also, I want to know the reason behind that why we don't offer tulsi to Ganesha except for Ganesha Chaturthi day during patri puja?

Comment: Durva Grass is the favorite of Ganapaty,Bilwa leaves of Lord Shiva and Tulasi leaves are that of Lord Vishnu.I was aware that it is an offence to offer Tulasi leaves to Lord Shiva but didn't know that it is the same with Lord Ganapaty too.It is even strictly prohibited to pour Shiva Puja Nirmalaya on a Tulasi plant.

Comment: No offence in offering Tulasi leaves to Lord Shiva. Bilvastakam talks about 'panchabilwam'.Among that Tulasi is one type of bilvam and can offer to Lord Shiva.

Comment: This is as much as i know as to why Tulasi leaves are never used in a Shiva Puja:http://www.hindu-blog.com/2011/09/why-tulsi-leaves-are-not-offered-to.html

Comment: The Bilva Ashtakam that i'm aware of   does not mention about  anything called "Pancha Bilwam" anywhere.See this:http://www.bharatiweb.com/wp-content/uploads/Bilvashtakam-Eng-v1.pdf

Comment: Please note my question is not exactly duplicate. It is a unique query on story or reason behind for Tulsi offering only on Ganesh Chaturthi day(Only one instance) and not offering on remaining days.

Comment: @Rickross: please find for `Bilva Asthothara shathanama sthotram`. In that you can see as Panchabilvam. In sanskrit: `तुलसीबिल्वनिर्गुण्डी जम्बीरामलकं तथा ।
पञ्चबिल्वमिति ख्यातं एकबिल्वं शिवार्पणम् ॥ ९४॥`

Comment: Yes i now have found examples from scriptures that in some Ksetras Lord Shiva is offered Tulasi leaves.

Comment: Tulsi itself one of the  Bilvam among `Pancha Bilvam` offered to Lord Shiva.

Comment: I think u are referring to the Bilwa astottara stotram by adi shankara.Did u find any referrences of "pancha bilwam" in any hindu scriptures apart from this stotram?

Comment: Not sure.......

Comment: Tulsi is also offered at Lingarag temple in Bhubaneswar (Odisha) since centuries, the presiding deity being HariHara, an amalgamation of shaivism and Vaishnavism